# Keyboard Layout Table – how to force update?

Tags: keyboard-layout

After creating a custom keyboard layout, a table picturing the layout in a nice graphical representation was automatically created.
It can be accessed from the keyboard icon.
It opens in a separate window, cf. below:

[image]

However, this table isn't updated after making changes to an already existing layout (even not after rebooting).
This is annoying, since now the picture doesn't correspond to the actual keyboard layout, but rather to the original one, before making any changes. It is just never updated after a keyboard layout is created with a new name.

Removing the keyboard layout from `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/` and creating it again doesn't help; the table seems to be cached somewhere.

I have no idea where this picture (or whatever it be) is saved, I don't even know what program creates it (it doesn't look too much like the ps-files created by `xkbprint`). Maybe deleting the *table* (not the keyboard layout) would do the job, but since I don't know where it is, I couldn't try.

I'd appreciate any hint on how I can force this table to be updated, so to fit my modified keyboard layout.

(I'm using Precise with Unity.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cache of (compiled) keyboard layouts is kept in the `/var/lib/xkb/` directory, in the various `*.xkm` files.  Perhaps deleting these files may help?  There is a `README` in that directory giving a bit more information.

Comment: This looks promising, thanks @PLL ! I can't find the README, however... It's in the same directory, you say?

Comment: For me (running 14.04), yes, it is in the same directory: `/var/lib/xkb/README.compiled`.  I don’t know if it exists in earlier releases, I’m afraid. In any case, though, you can (as I understand it) safely delete the `*.xkm` files; they are recreated the next time you visit the Tex Entry Settings panel.

Comment: This is it! It worked! Deleting those did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the only solution is to restart X server, either by re-logging in / rebooting, or by:

```
$ sudo restart lightdm
```

Comment: thanks, but neither rebooting nor restarting `lightdm` cause the layout table to update...

Comment: Sorry if I didn't help, I thought this would help. I'll look into it some more and let you know. For now I can only tell you that the keyboard chart is not an image, and it is not being cached anywhere, i.e. it is most definitely possible to change it. I'll just have to re-think about how to do it :)